# Where can I read the Pancharatra Agamas online in English?

Tags: vaishnavism, agamas, resource, pancharatra

I would like to begin reading the Pancharatra Agamas in English. Can anybody provide me the relevant links or PDFs for them?

Comment: Only a small number of them have ever been translated into English.

Comment: I myself want to read them in detail as well. Are any of them available even if in Sanskrit? If so can someone share the resource where they can be obtained?

Comment: @SuryaKantaBoseChowdhury Why had you deleted the answer? I've revised the answer and undeleted it. Tell/reply if you find any issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read some of the Pancharatra Agamas translated in English [here](https://archive.org/details/pancaratra-agamas).

It's following works included as described:

> A collection of published works on the Pancaratra Agamas in the last century. The contents Include:
>
> 1. Catalogues of Pancaratra Agama and Samhita Texts,
> 2. Agama Pramanya of Yamunacharya
> 3. Sri Pancaratra Raksha of Vedanta Desika
> 4. Ahirbudhniya Samhita,
> 5. Aniruddha Samhita,
> 6. Bharadvaja Samhita of the Narada Pancaratra,
> 7. Brhat Brahma Samhita of the Narada Pancaratra,
> 8. Ishvara Samhita,
> 9. Jayakhya Samhita,
> 10. Kapinjala Samhita,
> 11. Kashyapa Samhita,
> 12. Lakshmi Tantra,
> 13. Narayana Samhita,
> 14. Padma Samhita,
> 15. Parama Samhita,
> 16. Parameshvara Samhita,
> 17. Parasara Samhita,
> 18. Paushkara Samhita,
> 19. Sanatkumara Samhita,
> 20. Sandilya Samhita,
> 21. Sattvata Tantra/Samhita and
> 22. Vishnu Samhita.

Here are the separate links if you're finding difficulty to get them:

[**1**
                    Agama Pramanyam [Skt-Eng]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Agama%20Pramanyam%20%5BSkt-Eng%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**2**
                    Agama_Pramanyam_1937](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Agama_Pramanyam_1937)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**3**
                    Agamas & South Indian Vaishnavism](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Agamas%20%26%20South%20Indian%20Vaishnavism)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**4**
                    Ahirbudhniya Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Ahirbudhniya%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**5**
                    Ahirbudhnya Samhita [Skt] - Vol II](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Ahirbudhnya%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D%20-%20Vol%20II)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**6**
                    Ahirbudhnya Samhita [Skt] - Vol I](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Ahirbudhnya%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D%20-%20Vol%20I)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**7**
                    Aniruddha Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Aniruddha%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**8**
                    Bharadwaja Samhita [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Bharadwaja%20Samhita%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**9**
                    Brhat Brahma Samhita of Narada Pancaratra](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Brhat%20Brahma%20Samhita%20of%20Narada%20Pancaratra)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**10**
                    Brhat Brahma Samhita](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Brhat%20Brahma%20Samhita)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**11**
                    Catalogue of Pancaratra Agama Texts](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Catalogue%20of%20Pancaratra%20Agama%20Texts)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**12**
                    Catalogue of Pancaratra Samhitha](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Catalogue%20of%20Pancaratra%20Samhitha)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**13**
                    Introduction to Pancaratra & Ahirbudniya Samhita](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Introduction%20to%20Pancaratra%20%26%20Ahirbudniya%20Samhita)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**14**
                    Ishvara Samhita - Sastra Muktavali [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Ishvara%20Samhita%20-%20Sastra%20Muktavali%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**15**
                    Ishvara Samhita [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Ishvara%20Samhita%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**16**
                    Jayakhya Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Jayakhya%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**17**
                    Kapinjala Samhita [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Kapinjala%20Samhita%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**18**
                    Kasyapa Samhita - Vol I [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Kasyapa%20Samhita%20-%20Vol%20I%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**19**
                    Kasyapa Samhita - Vol II [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Kasyapa%20Samhita%20-%20Vol%20II%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**20**
                    Kasyapa Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Kasyapa%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**21**
                    Lakshmi Tantra [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Lakshmi%20Tantra%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**22**
                    Narada Pancaratra - Bharadvaja Samhita[Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Narada%20Pancaratra%20-%20Bharadvaja%20Samhita%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**23**
                    Narada Pancaratra - Bharadwaja Samhita [1865]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Narada%20Pancaratra%20-%20Bharadwaja%20Samhita%20%5B1865%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**24**
                    Narayana Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Narayana%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**25**
                    Padma Samhita - Charyapada [Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Padma%20Samhita%20-%20Charyapada%20%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**26**
                    Padma Samhita - Gnana,Yoga&Kriya Padas [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Padma%20Samhita%20-%20Gnana%2CYoga%26Kriya%20Padas%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**27**
                    Padma Samhita - Kriyapada[Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Padma%20Samhita%20-%20Kriyapada%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**28**
                    Padma Samhita - Yoga Pada[Tel]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Padma%20Samhita%20-%20Yoga%20Pada%5BTel%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**29**
                    Pancaratra Samhitausu Jnanapada Samikshanam [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Pancaratra%20Samhitausu%20Jnanapada%20Samikshanam%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**30**
                    Pancharatra Raksha [1942]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Pancharatra%20Raksha%20%5B1942%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**31**
                    Pancharatra Raksha [1967]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Pancharatra%20Raksha%20%5B1967%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**32**
                    Pancharatra Raksha [PBA]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Pancharatra%20Raksha%20%5BPBA%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**33**
                    Parama Samhita [Skt-Eng]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Parama%20Samhita%20%5BSkt-Eng%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**34**
                    Paramesvara Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Paramesvara%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**35**
                    Parasara Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Parasara%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**36**
                    Paushkara Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Paushkara%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**37**
                    Philosophy of Pancaratras](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Philosophy%20of%20Pancaratras)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**38**
                    Sanatkumar Samhita [Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sanatkumar%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**39**
                    Sandilya_Samhita_Bhakti_Kanda](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sandilya_Samhita_Bhakti_Kanda)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**40**
                    Sattvata Samhita - Alasinga Bhatta[Skt]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sattvata%20Samhita%20-%20Alasinga%20Bhatta%5BSkt%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**41**
                    Sattvata Samhita [Skt,1902]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sattvata%20Samhita%20%5BSkt%2C1902%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**42**
                    Sattvata_Tantra [1934]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sattvata_Tantra%20%5B1934%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**43**
                    Sattvata_Tantra [Eng]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sattvata_Tantra%20%5BEng%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**44**
                    Sri Pancharatra Karshanadi Pratisthanta](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Sri%20Pancharatra%20Karshanadi%20Pratisthanta)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**45**
                    The Pancharatras or Bhagavad Sastra](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/The%20Pancharatras%20or%20Bhagavad%20Sastra)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**46**
                    Vishnu Samhita - Part I [Eng]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Vishnu%20Samhita%20-%20Part%20I%20%5BEng%5D)

                  
                
                              
                  
                    [**47**
                    Vishnu Samhita - Part II [Eng]](http://archive.org/stream/pancaratra-agamas/Vishnu%20Samhita%20-%20Part%20II%20%5BEng%5D)

Note: some of them are in Sanskrit or Telugu and not translated into English.